# Big Join syntax assistance

Tags: sqlite, join

a bit of a long shot here with a slightly confusing one

I have the following 4 queries which when run in order produce 104 rows. The sequence is as follows;

```
select *
from borrow
where personid = 14
```

looking for transactionid here - returns 791 & 1314

```
select *
from borrow_copy
where transactionid IN (791, 1314)
```

Looking for bookdescid here - returns 126 and 110

```
select *
from book
where bookdescid IN (126, 110)
```

Looking for subjectid here - returns 12 11

```
select *
from book
where subjectid IN (12,11)
```

Looking for all books with the subjectid 12 and 11 here. Returns row count of 104

I am basically trying to join all of these steps above into one query which ultimately returns the title and subtitle of all books which have subjectid 12 or 11. I have attempted this in the query below which will demonstrate what columns are in each table, yet I cannot seem to finish it off

I believe the query below completes step 2 in the sequence as it returns the correct 2 books which then identify the subjectid's needed in the final results as 12 and 11

```
SELECT title, subtitle
FROM book
JOIN book_copy ON book.bookdescid = book_copy.bookdescid
JOIN borrow_copy ON book_copy.bookid = borrow_copy.bookid
JOIN borrow ON borrow_copy.transactionid = borrow.transactionid
JOIN person ON borrow.personid = person.personid
WHERE borrow_copy.transactionid IN(
SELECT borrow_copy.transactionid
FROM borrow_copy
WHERE borrow.personid = 14)
```

Basically i am stuck at this point as I am unsure how to say that of the 2 records returned from the query above - use the subjectid column to now return me all of the title & subtitle from the book table where the subjectid is the same

---

### Step 1:

[image]

### Step 2:

[image]

### Step 3:

[image]

### Step 4:

[image]

---

```
SELECT
    title,
    subtitle
FROM
    book
    JOIN book_copy ON book.bookdescid = book_copy.bookdescid
    JOIN borrow_copy ON book_copy.bookid = borrow_copy.bookid
    JOIN borrow ON borrow_copy.transactionid = borrow.transactionid
    JOIN person ON borrow.personid = person.personid
WHERE
    borrow_copy.transactionid IN
    (
        SELECT
            borrow_copy.transactionid
        FROM
            borrow_copy
        WHERE
            borrow.personid = 14 IN
            (
                SELECT
                    NULL
                FROM
                    book
                WHERE
                    book.bookdescid IN
                    (
                        SELECT
                            NULL
                        FROM
                            book
                        WHERE
                            book.subjectid = book.subjectid
                    )
            )
    );
```

Comment: Step 1 - https://prnt.sc/vffu0d

Step 2 - https://prnt.sc/vffu8r

Step 3 - https://prnt.sc/vffuf0

Step 4 - (final) https://prnt.sc/vffukp

Comment: Avoid using `WHERE x IN ( SELECT y FROM z )` to filter results when you're already JOINing the same tables - you'll end up confused.

Comment: You say you only want `title` and `subtitle` from the `book` table based on the book's subject - so why are you using `borrow` and `borrow_copy` and `book_copy` - how are they relevant to the query? Why are you referencing them?

Comment: Thanks @Dai. I'm a bit of a rookie so I don't actually know the correct process for this. Just trying to get the result

Comment: @Dai you need `borrow` to identify the `transactionid` numbers, you need `borrow_copy` to identify the `bookid` and you need `book_copy` to identify `bookdescid`

Comment: @Dai have a look at the screenshots in my first comment. It shows the sequence if you do it one by one and the results taken from each step

Comment: Was able to get to this but it definitely isn't correct;

`SELECT title, subtitle
FROM book
JOIN book_copy ON book.bookdescid = book_copy.bookdescid
JOIN borrow_copy ON book_copy.bookid = borrow_copy.bookid
JOIN borrow ON borrow_copy.transactionid = borrow.transactionid
JOIN person ON borrow.personid = person.personid
WHERE borrow_copy.transactionid IN (
  SELECT borrow_copy.transactionid
  FROM borrow_copy
WHERE borrow.personid = 14 IN (
  SELECT NULL
  FROM book
  WHERE book.bookdescid IN(
    SELECT NULL
    FROM book
    WHERE book.subjectid = book.subjectid)));`

Comment: What is the difference between `book` and `book_copy`, and `borrow` and `borrow_copy`?

Comment: @Dai
• book - Contains information about the books that are available in the library. Every book can have one or more physical copies in the collection. 
• book_copy- Keeps track of the physical copies of the books in the library collection.
• borrow- Keeps track of the check-ins and check-outs of the books. Every transaction is done by one person, however may involve with one or more book copies.
• borrow_copy- Associates physical copies of books with a transaction.

Comment: I assume this is for an undergraduate-level CS database course. Have you covered CTEs (Common Table Expressions) in your course yet, or only `JOIN`s?

Comment: @Dai yes have covered CTEs but the challenge of this module is pulling all of them together when trying to join and using the results of one subselect in the 2nd subselect

Comment: @Dai i might add probably only the basic common expressions, hence why i am struggling with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a preface: remember that in a `SELECT` statement, the *logical* evaluation order is actually:

1. `FROM`
2. `WHERE`
3. `GROUP BY`
4. `HAVING`
5. `SELECT`
6. `ORDER BY`

(You can blame some IBM managers in the 1970s for the reason why `SELECT` comes first - they wanted to make queries appear like natural language English so PHBs could try to understand them, but it ended up making the language a mess and unfortunately it's an ISO standard now with probably thousands of separate implementations from hundreds of different companies and teams, so this wont be changing any time soon)

And the `FROM` clause can contain infinitely many other nested subqueries (generally speaking: if you're putting a `SELECT x FROM y` in a `SELECT` clause instead of the `FROM` clause then you're probably doing something wrong).

---

First-off, document the tables via `CREATE TABLE` statements. That's easier than looking at screenshots:

```
CREATE TABLE book (
    bookDescId int,
    title      varchar,
    subtitle   varchar,
    edition    varchar,
    etc        varchar,
    subjectId  int,

    CONSTRAINT PK_book PRIMARY KEY ( bookDescId )
)

CREATE TABLE book_copy (
    bookDescId int,
    bookId     int,

    CONSTRAINT PK_book_copy PRIMARY KEY ( bookId )
)

CREATE TABLE borrow (
    transactionId int,
    personId      int,
    etc           date,

    CONSTRAINT PK_borrow PRIMARY KEY ( transactionId ),
    CONSTRAINT FK_borrow_TO_person ( personId ) REFERENCES person ( personId )
)

CREATE TABLE borrow_copy (
    transactionId int,
    bookId        int

    CONSTRAINT PK_borrow_copy PRIMARY KEY ( transactionId, bookId ),
    CONSTRAINT FK_borrow_copy_TO_borrow ( transactionId ) REFERENCES borrow ( transactionId )
    CONSTRAINT FK_borrow_copy_TO_book_copy ( bookId ) REFERENCES book_copy ( bookId )
)
```

With that out of the way, let's work outwards, not inwards:

Here's all the borrow transactions from person 14:

```
SELECT
    borrow.*
FROM
    borrow
WHERE
    borrow.personId = 14
```

We can `INNER JOIN` with `borrow_copy` to get the `bookIds` of all books that person 14 ever borrowed (a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` would also work, assuming your database has relational integrity, but `INNER JOIN` expresses intent better):

```
SELECT
    borrow_copy.bookId
FROM
    borrow
    INNER JOIN borrow_copy ON borrow.transactionId = borrow_copy.transactionId
WHERE
    borrow.personId = 14
```

Then we can `INNER JOIN` that again with `book_copy` to get the `bookDescId` from `bookId`:

```
SELECT
    borrow_copy.bookId,
    book_copy.bookDescId
FROM
    borrow
    INNER JOIN borrow_copy ON borrow.transactionId = borrow_copy.transactionId
    INNER JOIN book_copy   ON book_copy.bookId = borrow_copy.bookId
WHERE
    borrow.personId = 14
```

Then `INNER JOIN` again to get the book's details:

```
SELECT
    borrow_copy.bookId,
    book_copy.bookDescId,
    book.title,
    book.subtitle
FROM
    borrow
    INNER JOIN borrow_copy ON borrow.transactionId = borrow_copy.transactionId
    INNER JOIN book_copy   ON book_copy.bookId = borrow_copy.bookId
    INNER JOIN book        ON book.bookDescId = book_copy.bookDescId
WHERE
    borrow.personId = 14
```

As you just want `title` and `subtitle`, remove unwanted columns from the `SELECT` clause and change it from `SELECT` to `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove duplicates (this is one of many special-case shorthands in SQL to eliminate the need for a `GROUP BY *` clause):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    book.title,
    book.subtitle
FROM
    borrow_copy
    INNER JOIN borrow    ON borrow_copy.transactionId = borrow.transactionId
    INNER JOIN book_copy ON borrow_copy.bookId = book_copy.bookId
    INNER JOIN book      ON book.bookDescId = book_copy.bookDescId
WHERE
    personId = 14
```

---

> of these books which person 14 has borrowed, now show me all of the title, subtitles in the book table which have the same subjectid as the books that person 14 borrowed.

That's straightforward: change the above query to return distinct `subjectId` values, then `INNER JOIN` that on `book` *again* (which will require aliasing the `book` table):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    sameSubjectBooks.title,
    sameSubjectBooks.subtitle
FROM
    borrow_copy
    INNER JOIN borrow                   ON borrow_copy.transactionId = borrow.transactionId
    INNER JOIN book_copy                ON borrow_copy.bookId = book_copy.bookId
    INNER JOIN book AS b                ON b.bookDescId = book_copy.bookDescId
    INNER JOIN book AS sameSubjectBooks ON sameSubjectBooks.subjectId = b.subjectId
WHERE
    personId = 14
```

Comment: Thanks very much for all of that @Dai, really appreciate it. I have saved all of that for reference material as well, that's great. Noted regarding the layout and order of operations as well. That's much cleaner and concise. Also noted regarding the create table statements. Awesome notes

I think there is one key part missing here though which is the end which says - of these books which person 14 has borrowed, now show me all of the title, subtitles in the book table which have the same subjectid as the books that person 14 borrowed. This is step 4 in my screenshots  https://prnt.sc/vffukp

Comment: The final statement you provided just returns all of the books person 14 has ever borrowed - https://prnt.sc/vfgd6h

Just need to understand the next layer which is to show all of the title, subtitles for the books that have the same subjectid as these 2 records

Comment: Thanks very much once again @Dai, that's worked a treat! I see how you have achieved that now in the cleanest way possible. Awesome notation of each step and I will definitely use this case again in the future.